# how to serve Twiml Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am having a hard time create my TWIML files with nodejs.
I am creating outbound calls and they work with a static XML file or twiml bin but not my endpoint.

do you know what is wrong?

```
app.post('/twiml-generator', function(req, res){
    var name = "billy";
    //Create TwiML response
    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

    twiml.say("Hello from your pals at Twilio! Have fun. Love " + name);

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
    res.end(twiml.toString());

});
```

then when i go to initiate the call

```
  client.calls.create({ 
    url: 'http://myHOSTEDsite.com/twiml-generator',//ISSUE HERE but if i use a twiml bin or static xml, it works// so my endpoint must be the issue 
    to: targetNumber, 
    from: "+14444444444", // my trail number 
    timeout: 12

  }, function(err, call) { 
    console.log("call made"); 
    //console.log(call)

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
res.end(twiml.toString());
```

try

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
res.send(twiml.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what Twilio doc says

```
response.type('text/xml');
response.send(twiml.toString());
```